# WooCommerce error: Coupon properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, coupon

**1°** For necessity, i created this condition inside the template **order-details.php** file and i know that, this is not recommended.

**2°** Now i must put this script inside a filter to run in the **order-details.php (checkout page)**.

**3°** Problem: Always when i apply a coupom code for the product and i **place the order**, i receive the following error message in the **debug.log** file

```
[20-Nov-2020 14:19:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  code was called <strong> incorrectly </strong>.
Coupon properties should not be accessed directly.
Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
include('/themes/astra/page.php'),
astra_content_page_loop,
do_action('astra_content_page_loop'),
WP_Hook->do_action,
WP_Hook->apply_filters, Astra_Loop->loop_markup_page, Astra_Loop->loop_markup,
do_action('astra_page_template_parts_content'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
Astra_Loop->template_parts_page, get_template_part, locate_template, load_template,
require('/themes/astra/template-parts/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'),
WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, 
WC_Shortcodes::checkout, WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::output,
WC_Shortcode_Checkout::order_received, wc_get_template, include('/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/
checkout/thankyou.php'), do_action('woocommerce_thankyou'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->app in 
C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\mrdigital\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5229
```

This is my **order-details.php** (checkout page) file

```
<?php
/**
 * Order details
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 4.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited

if ( ! $order ) {
    return;
}

$order_items           = $order->get_items( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_purchase_order_item_types', 'line_item' ) );
$show_purchase_note    = $order->has_status( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_purchase_note_order_statuses', array( 'completed', 'processing' ) ) );
// $show_customer_details = true; 
// Para exibir o template ENDEREÇO DE FATURAMENTO na página
$show_customer_details = is_user_logged_in() && $order->get_user_id() === get_current_user_id();
$downloads             = $order->get_downloadable_items();
$show_downloads        = $order->has_downloadable_item() && $order->is_download_permitted();

if ( $show_downloads ) {
    wc_get_template(
        'order/order-downloads.php',
        array(
            'downloads'  => $downloads,
            'show_title' => true,
        )
    );
}
?>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="text-right">
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" class="button">P&aacute;gina Inicial</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<section class="woocommerce-order-details">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table', $order ); ?>

    <h2 class="woocommerce-order-details__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <table class="woocommerce-table woocommerce-table--order-details shop_table order_details">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="woocommerce-table__product-table product-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items', $order );

            foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
                $product = $item->get_product();

                wc_get_template(
                    'order/order-details-item.php',
                    array(
                        'order'              => $order,
                        'item_id'            => $item_id,
                        'item'               => $item,
                        'show_purchase_note' => $show_purchase_note,
                        'purchase_note'      => $product ? $product->get_purchase_note() : '',
                        'product'            => $product,
                    )
                );
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table_items', $order );
            ?>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <?php
            foreach ( $order->get_order_item_totals() as $key => $total ) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo esc_html( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo ( 'payment_method' === $key ) ? esc_html( $total['value'] ) : wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
            }
// **** Inserted Lines - Coupon Start ****

            if( $order->get_coupon_codes() ) {
            foreach( $order->get_coupon_codes() as $code) {
                // Pick up the object of each coupon
                $coupon = new WC_Coupon($code);
                 ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Cupom</th>
            <!-- Print the Coupon Code -->
            <td><?php echo $coupon->code; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Coupon Expiration Date</th>
            <!-- Print Coupon Expiration Date -->
            <td><?php print_r($coupon->get_date_expires()->date('d-m-Y')); ?></td>
        </tr>
           <?php  } 
            }

// **** Inserted Lines - Coupon End ****
             if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Note:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( nl2br( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ) ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', $order ); ?>
</section>

<?php
/**
 * Action hook fired after the order details.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 * @param WC_Order $order Order data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_details', $order );

if ( $show_customer_details ) {
    wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-customer.php', array( 'order' => $order ) );
}
```

**Just the Coupon Script to be seen::**

```
// **** Inserted Lines - Coupon Start ****

            if( $order->get_coupon_codes() ) {
            foreach( $order->get_coupon_codes() as $code) {
                // Pick up the object of each coupon
                $coupon = new WC_Coupon($code);
                 ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Coupon</th>
            <!-- Print the Coupon Code -->
            <td><?php echo $coupon->code; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Coupon Expiration Date</th>
            <!-- Print Coupon Expiration Date -->
            <td><?php print_r($coupon->get_date_expires()->date('d-m-Y')); ?></td>
        </tr>
           <?php  } 
            }

// **** Inserted Lines - Coupon End ****
```

**4°** What filter should i use in the functions.php file to generate the same result (without trigger  error message) and how this should look like please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, you need to use the [`WC_coupon` method `get_code()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.0/includes/class-wc-coupon.php#L163-L172) instead of trying to access the coupon "code" property directly, so you will have to replace in your code:

```php
            <!-- Print the Coupon Code -->
            <td><?php echo $coupon->code; ?></td>
```

simply by

```php
            <!-- Print the Coupon Code -->
            <td><?php echo $coupon->get_code(); ?></td>
```

This will solve this issue.

---

You can use `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` filter hook, instead of overriding `order-details.php` template, to add some custom lines to order total displayed lines.

See [those examples using `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` filter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_get_order_item_totals).

Comment: Hello @loictheaztec! Thank you so much Again! Merci beaucoup! The first answer works like a charm `$coupon->get_code();` , now i need to get the filter up and running. Just a moment and i'll comeback here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Huge Help! I got the code running!